# How can I use the Mac OS Cmd-tab app switcher when controlling my Mac Mini remotely?

Tags: mac, keyboard, remote-desktop

**Problem**:
I control my 2018 Mac Mini using Real VNC software from my iPhone or iPads.  When I enter Cmd-tab on the iOS device, the command is interpreted locally and not on the remote Mac Mini.  Accordingly, because I cannot use keystrokes on the iOS device to invoke the app switcher on the remote Mac Mini, I have to move the cursor to the dock to find the application I want to use.  This is very slow.

I have a home subscription to Real VNC, which prohibits accessing Real VNC's support team for technical support.  Nothing I have found on their site has helped me.

**Issue:**
The issue is in getting the iOS device to interpret keystrokes using modifier keys as applicable to the remote machine.

**Steps taken:**
I have downloaded Karabiner-Elements.  It is recommended for reassigning functions to keystrokes. I have not yet attempted to use it to address the problem, because I am guessing it will take me some time to learn and become familiar with it.

**I need help ...:**
So, my question has these parts:

1. can I get Real VNC to work so that I can switch apps on the remote Mac Mini by using keyboard shortcuts on my iOS devices?
2. if so, do I need to reassign functions to keystrokes on the iOS devices and/or on the Mac Mini, and if I do, is Karabiner Elements a good way to do this?
3. is there any other remote connection software available, preferably free, that will enable me to remotely control the Mac OS app switcher from an iOS device?  (Reviews on remote connection software comparison sites do not easily reveal answers on details such as this).

Comment: The general way to deal with this type of conflict, if the software itself fails to differentiate, is to change the defaults on the machine in hand. Unfortunately, Cmd/Tab is a universal default you cannot override. I very rarely remote from an iOS device so I'm out of touch with what software is currently available. My old app (now long gone)  did have specific differentiation for such as that scenario. I frequently remote between Macs & have just learned to live without that particular command; others I've changed my local commands to avoid the conflict.

Comment: Sounds like you must have a keyboard attached to your phone or iPad *and* that Cmd-Tab works locally on those devices?  That's new to me.  On Windows, remote-desktop apps usually allow you to designate keys (like Alt) as "pass-thru", meaning the app will pass-thru the key command to the remote computer.  Look for a setting like that in your iOS/iPadOS apps.  Or change the default shortcut keys on your Mac (or iPhone/iPad, if that's possible).

Comment: Cmd-Tab operates locally on iOS devices whether using built-in keyboards or, eg, bluetooth keyboards, such as Logitech K380 multi-device keyboards.